# Android: running a service with a broadcast receiver.

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I have this app that I want to run at phone start up (As in after the GUI comes up) but I want it to run in the background(like a service)

I know this is possible, since most of the android system is like this.

Any tips would be wonderful!

Comment: What kind of tips? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a service in your app. Bind it to an Activity if you wish. 
Subclass BroadcastReceiver to listen to the Android.BOOT_COMPLETED system broadcast.
then start your service.

Comment: Hey man thanks for the tip, that helped out quite a bit Now I just need to figure out the service thing and this will be peachy!

Comment: The service part is equally easy because you can start and stop it from your Application Context. All you have to do is call startService(Intent intent). Make sure to stop your service if it isn't needed as it will slow system performance.